# jQuery UI tabs in behaviors.js

Tags: javascript

I want to use my theme's behaviors.js (not template.php etc) to create jQuery UI tabs.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/webdevem/p3sfy/) is an example of jQuery UI tabs where the js is

```
$("#tabs").tabs();
```

My html =

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Tab 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Tab 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-3">Tab 3</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
        <p>Content for Tab 1</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2">
        <p>Content for Tab 2</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-3">
        <p>Content for Tab 3</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

My [bartik.behaviors.js](http://test030714.click-monkey.net/themes/bartik/js/bartik.behaviors.js) =

```
(function ($) {
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#tabs").tabs();
});
})(jQuery);
```

but as you can see on my Drupal 7 site [here](http://test030714.click-monkey.net/node/1) the tabs are not rendered.

Question: What is the correct code for my bartik.behaviors.js ?